# attempt to invoke directory as script?

Tags: httpd, scriptalias

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        AddHandler cgi-script pl cgi
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

what did i do wrong ??

Comment: please post your error log and be more precise what your are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Change the ScriptAlias to an Alias.

Answer (score 2):

This means that you tried to invoke the URL ending with **http://example.com/cgi-bin/** in the browser's location bar without specifying an actual CGI script to execute (i.e.: ../cgi-bin/script.cgi). Your code indicates no problem at all.

Though you might want to enclose the parameters to your **ScriptAlias** [directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias) within double quotation marks as shown below:

```
ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
```